# Dynamic data preserve changes in the child component

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

How can we render dynamic data but preserve the state/change in a loop?

I am trying to create a dynamic number of tabs and the contents of the tab are dynamic. I can add/remove tabs. Here is a [sample implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/revogrid-svelte-playground-i66kh?file=/App.svelte) of what I am trying to do.

In the above example, I have the contents of the table as soon as it is created. I can resize the table as and when I want. If I switch tabs the changes are gone(for example sort the table or resize the columns).

How can I preserve the changes on navigation change?

Comment: Have you tried using svelte stores?

Comment: I have. How would svelte store help here exactly? When the list of tabs or the table change will the render not kick in? In my implementation I am using a list and when the list changes it gets rendered again. This is good but I do not want the existing changes like resize etc get effected when it is rerendered.